# Finding the value of a Component clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple Component class in ReactJS described as below. I want to get the value of the name field when the button is clicked.

```
var Movie = React.createClass({

handleBuy: function(){
    console.log('tried adding to array');
    cartItems.push({ id: 2, title: "Sholay", visible: false });
    console.log('tried adding to array............');
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <tr>
        <td>{this.props.movie.name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.movie.day}</td>
        <td>{this.props.movie.description}</td>
        <td><button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleBuy}>Buy Ticket</button></td>
        </tr>);
    }
```

});

I want to print this.props.movie.name for the Row in which the Button was clicked but I don't seem to get it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke `this.handleBuy` with some params that is all...

```
<button
  className="btn btn-info"
  onClick={() => this.handleBuy(<the data you care about>)}
>
  Buy Ticket
</button>
```